# Do namespaces affect initialization order in C++?

Tags: c++, static, namespaces, initialization

Global variables are initialized in order of appearing in the translation module and the relative order of initialization of variables in different translation modules in unspecified (so-called "static initialization order fiasco").

Do namespaces have any influence on that? For example if I have this code:

```
//first.cpp
int first;
int second;
```

will it have any difference in initialization order compared to this code:

```
//second.cpp
namespace {
int first;
}
int second;
```

Are there cases where putting a global object into a namespace affects initialization order?

Comment: Be aware the the C++ standard defines that global names are only those that appear in the global scope ([basic.scope.namespace]/3). So as far as C++ is concerned, in second.cpp `first` is not a global. Obviously for all practical purposes to do with "globals" and especially mutable "globals" being a PITA to work with, in all programming languages, it's a "global".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> 3.6 Other non-local variables with static storage duration have ordered initialization. Variables
>   with ordered initialization deﬁned within a single translation unit shall be initialized in the order of their
>   deﬁnitions in the translation unit.

Namespaces have no effect on this - not mentioned in the section.

What does effect the order is different translation units. If you need to define the order across them, use an extension such as GCC's `constructor` attribute.

Comment: Rather than using extensions to control the order, I would recommend to avoid the dependency altogether.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Even better, avoid static storage.

Answer (score 5):

Well, the "Global variables are initialized in order of appearing in the translation module" is definite. It does not leave any room for anything else, like namespaces, to affect the order.

Actually, "Global variables are initialized in order ..." is imprecise quotation of the standard as is formally wrong. The exact wording from C++ Standard, ISO/IEC 14882:2003, 3.6.2 paragraph 1 is:

> Objects with static storage duration defined in namespace scope in the same translation
>   unit and dynamically initialized shall be initialized in the order in which their definition appears in the translation unit.

So rather than "global" it says "with static storage", that is all non-local variables whether they are global, namespace members or class members and whether they are declared `static` or not.

Also it adds "and dynamically initialized". Variables with trivial constructors and constant initializer are always initialized first (by simply loading their values from the binary) and than all non-constant initializers are evaluated and non-trivial constructors are run in that order. This is important, so you can for example reliably create a linked list in those constructors; if it's head is plain pointer, it is already initialized, so you can safely work with it.

Comment: +1 for the emphasise : `the "Global variables are initialized in order of appearing in the translation module" is definite`. End of Story!

Comment: The "definite" sentence as stated only.affects global variables. stuff in user defined namespaces is not global

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Yes, they are global. You are forcing me to look the exact wording in the specification. Ok, here comes... (see edit).